# Gaps in Particle-Boids spawn

Tags: particles, physics

I want to create a firework-rocket 
, which is starting. I am using Boid particles to create the sparks, but when the sphere goes up the path the particles don't spawn consistent, there are gaps between some spawn places. [image]

Comment: Not having access to file makes it hard to guess, but are your particles spawned continuously or only every few frames?

Comment: That is because at each frame as the rocket goes up, it is adding the particles. At no point in time is your rocket physically in those "gaps," so the particles are never added in there.

Comment: Since I'm quite new to Blender I can't answer that question. Maybe you could tell me the settings I can check that and how to change it.